# Install hubflow in Windows

Tags: git, hubflow

How to install hubflow in Windows?

I have tried the steps mentioned [in this link](https://gist.github.com/abhisekp/8f890be7f2b7bfb69603) but didn't work.

Comment: What error message do you have? What OS are you using? What git version do you have?